# Find an equation for the plane M that contains the point P and that is parallel to u and to v. Give the equation in the form ax + by + cz = d.

Tags: calculus, vectors

I'm asked to: find an equation for the plane M that contains the point P and that is parallel to u and to v. Give the equation in the form ax + by + cz = d.

Here is what is given:
*Deﬁne P(1,0,−1) and the vectors u = <3,−1,2> and v = <−1,1,−1>.*

I had to calculate the cross product of u*v at the previous question.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!! Please use MathJax to render correctly the math expressions. Also, please show us what have you tried so we can help you better.

Comment: Have you learned about the point-normal form of the equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The crossproduct is given by $$\vec{u}\times \vec{v}=[-1,1,2]$$ So we have found the cooefficients of the plane
$$-x+y+2z+d=0$$ Plugging $$x=1,y=0,z=-1$$ in this equation we will find $d$.

Comment: One Moment i will check this

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, i think it is to late (in the evening) for me!

Comment: What have you got for $d$?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer. I don't really get how we get to this. I have calculated the crossproduct (which I have verified with the solutions) to be: u*v = <-1,1,2>. I have then looked for the equation of the vector normal to u and v given by another crossproduct: [-3, -5, 2] (the one you have cited). But then I have been suggested by a classmate to assume an arbitrary point Q with PQ= <x-1, y-0, z+1> and to make a final DOTproduct this time in order to find the final equation: <x-1, y-0, z+1> . <-3, -5, 2>

Comment: I have got $$-x+y+2z+3=0$$. Have you a solution in your textbook?

Comment: Yes that is the solution on the textbook! But I don't get how to proceed to this answer.

Comment: The coordinates of the Vector $$\vec{u}\times \vec{v}$$  are the coefficients of our plane,$$(a,b,c)=(-1,1,2)$$

Comment: I think i have all written for you, can you finish now?

Comment: Oh right! I see now. the crossproduct gives the equation which can be used to find d which is finally 3 and gives the answer: $x-y-2z=3$. Thank you!

Comment: Fine, that we could solve your plane-question. Good night!